# get image from URL and Share image through intent android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I want to share image on share button. I use **Glide** to set image on ImageView. then I want to share particular image at that time I got *The file format is not supported* error.

```
private void shareContent(ImageView imageView) {
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

    Bitmap bitmap =getBitmapFromView(imageView);
    try {
        File file = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(),"logicchip.png");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        file.setReadable(true, false);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        intent.setType("image/png");
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) {
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }   else{
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

[REFERENCE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8cKb.jpg)

Comment: For share a bitmap you have to store it in public folder, for example DCIM or Picture by ContentResolver, then you can set URI to Extras of Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the bitmap you have generated via glide, don't try to take it from the view

Answer (score 0):

> > Uri.fromFile(file))

Do not use Uri.fromFile() but use FileProvider to get an uri and serve your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for image sharing. also use path provider in your manifest.

```
 StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
            Intent imageshare= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            imageshare.setType("Image/*");
           
            Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", path);
            imageshare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri );
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(imageshare, "Pick an Image provider"));
```

path provider in manifest inside application tag

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```